# SSMS Command Showing in Message Window with Completion time

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2017, ssms-19

I'm trying to find out what causes the command that was executed to show in the Messages window after execution.

For example, when altering a procedure, the message window shows "ALTER_PROCEDURE - [name of procedure here]".

This message shows on some of our servers, but not on others, so I'm trying to find out what setting to change to make it consistent.

Thank you!

I've been unsuccessful when searching here and in Google.

Comment: it is programmed into ssms, what is there to wonder

Comment: The version of SQL Server determines what is returned AFAIK - I have also noticed that.

Comment: Are they literally identical commands that have messages display differently? One doesn't have extra `print` statements, right?

Comment: You probably mean to preview command changes when changing e.g. table structure in the designer. For modifying a stored procedure, it's not needed as ssms always brings up the "alter procedure..." code into the query window.

Answer (score 0):

You can turn off the completion time messages by unchecking the box here:

Tools -> Options -> Query Execution -> SQL Server -> Advanced -> Show completion time

[image]